# How to add a license key through VB Script?

Tags: shell, vbscript

i am new to the vb script. I have installed a program and have to call an License.exe and fill the License name and license key. Batch file to add it into the reg key is not working on this app. So it would be great if you can help me in this.When i open the License.exe with installed product . it asks me to fill License Name and the License Key. I dont know how to create to add that key through script but i was able to call the .exe. here is an example.

```
Dim objShell    
Dim StrLicensename   
Dim StrLicensekey   
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" ) 
objShell.Run("""C:\ProgramFiles\Resources\licensing.exe""")

StrLicensename = CStr("Melbourne Victoria")  
StrLicensekey  = Cstr("1234-4567835")  
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you trying in first place to hardcode a key that's really bad idea for security?

Comment: You may try AutoIt for interacting with the application GUI, and VBS is wrong tool for such tasks.

Comment: @Mederic Well we need to package it and deploy through SCCM. Thats the reason our team was thinking to do ao rather than activating 50 machines manually.

Answer (score 0):

Well we need to package it and deploy through SCCM. Thats the reason our team was thinking to do ao rather than activating 50 machines manually.